# "No bootable device - insert boot disk" after restart on Ubuntu 10.04 b1 update

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-10.04

I was making an update on my Ubuntu 10.04 beta1 64-bit PC when, after reboot I get

> PXE-E61: Mediaa test failure, check
>   cable PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot
>   Agent.
>
> No bootable device - insert boot disk
>   and press any key

How did my boot record disappear ?

BIOS > Boot

```
Boot Menu Type : Normal
Boot Device Priority : <CD/DVD-ROM Drive>
                       <Hard Disk Drive>
                       <Floppy Drive>
                       <Ethernet>
Hard Driver Order    : No Hard Disk Drive
CD/DVD ROM Drive Order : <PT-TSSTcorp CDDV>
Removable Drive Order : No Removable Drive
Boot to Optical Devices : <Enable>
Boot to Removable Devices : <Enable>
Boot to Network : <Enable>
USB Boot : <Enable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried all sorts of things - finally opened the chassis - for some odd reason [the cable connecting to the hard-disk got burnt](http://anjanesh.blogspot.com/2010/04/hdd-media-cable-burnt.html). The computer was on the whole night though, but that shouldnt be a reason. Shouldnt be a voltage issue as Im connected to a 1kVA Delta UPS which handles the voltage fluctuations (if any).

Comment: well, that would have been the last option I was thinking about ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a grub (bootloader) problem.  I'd suggest booting from a live CD, mount the file systems from the disk, chrooting into them and using grub to re-install the bootloader.

I am of course assuming that you know how to do the above, based upon the fact that you're knowingly running a beta release operating system.